# react-native run-android hangs

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am starting a fresh app with react-native, and following the getting started tutorial [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html).  I have installed Android Studio, the sdk and avd files, and the react-native init seems to work ok...

```
react-native init myapp
>>
Installing React...
Installing Jest...
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
```

Then I try and run the app

```
react-native run-android
```

And it just hangs there (even left it overnight).

If I do an strace

```
...lots of stuff then
read(12, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nServer: Motion/3.2.12+git20140228\r\nConnection: close\r\nMax-Age: 0\r\nExpires: 0\r\nCache-Control: no-cache, private\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nContent-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--BoundaryString\r\n\r\n", 65536) = 217
epoll_wait(5, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=12, u64=12}}], 1024, -1) = 1
read(12, "--BoundaryString\r\nContent-type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Length:        4235\r\n\r\n\377\330\377\340\0\20JFIF\0\1\1\0\0\1\0\1\0\0\377\341\0\224Exif
```

And then keeps cycling with the line...

```
read(12, "--BoundaryString\r\nContent-type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Length:        4235\r\n\r\n\377\330\377\340\0\20JFIF.....
```

I have tried things like reinstalling react-native, the sdks etc, but error persists.

I have also seen a similar error linked to watchman with react-native init, but I don't think this would apply, as I don't currently have that installed (have tried with it installed previously).

I am using Linux Mint 18

```
4.4.0-51-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 24 18:29:54 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, it was a camera application using port 8081 that was causing the issue.

If I kill that process it works. I checked the ports in use by

```
netstat -tulpn
```

look for port 8081 in there, then

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

Assuming it's something you are happy not to have running, and change its config.

Would be handy if react-native checks for a port in use and reports it if it is, to save others having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Windows, you can try:

- Ctrl + Alt + Delete to bring up the Task Manager
- Select the "Node.js: Server-side Javascript" process
- Click the "End Task" button

Then try the `react-native run-android` command again.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

ran from Command Prompt as Administrator (that got the `react-native start` to run)

Then in the other command prompt when run-android I got after an extremely long wait: Could not determine java version from 10.

I upgraded gradlew in the [project]/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-src.zip
```

Then waited a long time for it to finish, seemingly doing nothing. 
Got a filenullpointer exception in findLauncherJar...

Read further and changed to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-all.zip
```

Then it hung with a message:

```
gradle refresh failed could not find com.android.tools buildg
```

Found SO 38702032  which suggested changes to the file Android/build.gradle and corrected the gradle version to 4.3.0

Got another error and went to http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/ to see what versions existed. Found that the last was 2.3.3

Put it back to what it was and added mavenCentral

Also checked that I have the paths (C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools)

and the three environment variables (c:\program files\java\sdk-10) and that I have the two ANDROID_HOME and ANDROID_SDK_HOME (c:\users\MyUsername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk) ...

rebooting and works.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Expo Go, hit a wall, went to expo-dev-client, hit another wall, so followed instructions for a basic react native project to see if I could get anywhere with that..... so I'm looking at a screen says `> react-native run-android` and nothing but tumbleweed; process list shows no activity, no progress feedback or error messages - zip as to any indication of the problem and no useful info anywhere online. I could wait but others have waited for hours in vain apparently. None of the other answers here or anything else I could find on the web worked.

In the end, I dunno why but, I ran `npm start` which launched Metro and hitting "a" launched the app on the emulator.

`npm run android` as per the official instructions still ends up at a (seemingly) hung `react-native run-android`